# How many numbers less than $1000$ with digit sum to $11$ and divisible by $11$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

How many positive (integers) numbers less than $1000$ with digit sum to $11$ and divisible by $11$?

There are $\lfloor 1000/11 \rfloor = 90$ numbers less than $1000$ divisible by $11$.

$N = 100a + 10b + c$ where $a + b + c  = 11$ and $0 \le a, b, c \le 9$

I got $\binom{13}{2} - 9 = 69$ solutions.

Comment: Not all N would be divisible by 11.

Comment: @GTXOC, how to find those, which are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digitsum is related to the modulo 9 operation.  A weakening of the conditions given is that you are counting how many $0\leq n\leq 1000$ satisfy the coungruencies:

$\begin{array}{} n\equiv 2\pmod{9}\\
n\equiv 0\pmod{11}\end{array}$

By the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), we get that

$n\equiv 11\pmod{99}$

So, we can look at the possible solutions and trim the ones that don't meet the stronger requirement that the digit sum be $11$ (as opposed to $2$ or $20$ or $29$ or $37$)

We have the list then $\{11,110,209,308,407,506,605,704,803,902\}$

All but the first two have digitsum 11 (whereas the first two have only digit sum equaling 2).

The answer is then $8$.

Answer (score 1):

$N=a+10b+100c$. $a-b+c=0$ or $a-b+c=11$. Also we have $a+b+c=11$. We get two cases:

- $a-b+c=0,\;a+b+c=11$ from which we get $2a+2b=11$; impossible.
- $a-b+c=11,\;a+b+c=11$ from which we get $a+c=11,\; b=0$. They are $209, 308, 407, 506, 605, 704, 803, 902$.